# How to block request domain in my website

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I have problem in my website, script `dan iframe` load in my website from other source and make load resource 17s.

my answer how to block request domain or block url script `dan iframe` like `blocked:devtool` in chrome from script. Or another ways to block request.
in case request from

> http://p01.notifa.info/3fsmd3/request?id=1&enc=9UwkxLgY9&params=4TtHaUQnUEiP6K%2fc5C582JKzDzTsXZH28lzpTd4lMOgVPmVP%2bxdGlUBoJkaQetwsDkZ1aSjgsc8C%2fu5F%2fweJtH5wqDRRzt%2f%2fbwErUKUxGlRSVxSVuGTdpL8UAkgIgw4ZgZoOIupjTSKLajX1MoRjudBzoxroHQ4SEO6n2%2bYyVPPhsCheWHKiSzaJfjxHmTJc8kH4nbMg55Dg8p6PclCGMyaFoC1Njzj7IJ2jYgXBDNUOOywppzn%2bX03DQL4JalUPfVJn9vvQYrwpz30U4s9HyQ6zy7r9esiN8R5D9CHdj%2fVMWThzxEeWO7R0fl1Uf8P%2fP3ufi1%2f8Bp1CZQFQgoFJN1ha2mrP8xmYK8IH1mGuhbbJiQTZFn7CqtxiBrJZV2d54QW8DqEyhkwp51kdgf0FKn2DHciVtW91IpXkTtbzlPkue%2f26HwADq0dTNUZYIofk6uCeVRkGwDHOMq2Ns6pyvS%2bFUAYKoPI%2frqpDEa2THtliuRq1QuCta3ZBsskcRen8Y%2blYC1cnmjTbCcDD9k54L6pNO9%2bY4N4c4alsioW56x4rN0d5ZaMCk5oN7CGQ3PcD1z6gl6uR0Bk%3d&idc_r=68588259417&domain=dev.mywebsite.com&sw=1440&sh=900

and

> http://x-tags.net/data/dmp/tag?p=1&tcid=28ac36f63de0197a3a5703065c7e491a0c313870

int tag `<head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://p01.notifa.info/3fsmd3/request?id=1&amp;enc=9UwkxLgY9&amp;params=4TtHaUQnUEiP6K%2fc5C582JKzDzTsXZH28lzpTd4lMOgVPmVP%2bxdGlUBoJkaQetwsDkZ1aSjgsc8C%2fu5F%2fweJtH5wqDRRzt%2f%2fbwErUKUxGlRSVxSVuGTdpL8UAkgIgw4ZgZoOIupjTSKLajX1MoRjudBzoxroHQ4SEO6n2%2bYyVPPhsCheWHKiSzaJfjxHmTJc8kH4nbMg55Dg8p6PclCGMyaFoC1Njzj7IJ2jYgXBDNUOOywppzn%2bX03DQL4JalUPfVJn9vvQYrwpz30U4s9HyQ6zy7r9esiN8R5D9CHdj%2fVMWThzxEeWO7R0fl1Uf8P%2fP3ufi1%2f8Bp1CZQFQgoFJN1ha2mrP8xmYK8IH1mGuhbbJiQTZFn7CqtxiBrJZV2d54QW8DqEyhkwp51kdgf0FKn2DHciVtW91IpXkTtbzlPkue%2f26HwADq0dTNUZYIofk6uCeVRkGwDHOMq2Ns6pyvS%2bFUAYKoPI%2frqpDEa2THtliuRq1QuCta3ZBsskcRen8Y%2blYC1cnmjTbCcDD9k54L6pNO9%2bY4N4c4alsioW56x4rN0d5ZaMCk5oN7CGQ3PcD1z6gl6uR0Bk%3d&amp;idc_r=68588259417&amp;domain=dev.mywebsite.com&amp;sw=1440&amp;sh=900"></script>
```

and load `iframe` after tag `

```
<iframe id="ifrm" scrolling="no" src="http://p01.notifa.info/campaign/log.php" style="height: 0px; width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border: 0px; padding: 0px;"></iframe>
```

Can someone can get me through this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: actually this injected from my Internet Service Provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Content-Security-Policy in header.

```
header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';");
```

This policy allows images, scripts, AJAX, and CSS from the same origin, and does not allow any other resources to load (eg object, frame, media, etc).

https://content-security-policy.com/

Comment: show error in console like `Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

Comment: It is default.  Allow what is necessary for your site.